# Render react icon based on comparison with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have the following array with data:

```
const colors = {
        Meeting: ["#D09FE8", GrGroup],
        "1on1": ["#86DB43", MdLocalLibrary],
        Review: ["#B22F5E", MdRateReview],
        "Team Collaboration": ["#B22F5E", RiStackshareFill],
        "Feature Review": ["#B22F5E", MdFeaturedPlayList],
    };
```

My react component is receiving a prop which contains a string of the meeting type, for example "Meeting". Based on that prop, i want to render a react icon.

Changing the background color is fine, I just did it as follows:

```
const style = {
        background: colors[`${eventData.meetingType}`][0],
}
```

But when trying to render the react icon, how can i do that here?

```
<div className="text-sm">{RENDER THE REACT ICON HERE}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render components using [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

```
<div className="text-sm">
    {/* Think of this as an if statement. */}
    { (meetingType === something) && (
        <img src={iconASrc} />
    )}

    {/* Conversely, this is an if-else statement. */}
    { (meetingType === something) ? (
        <img src={iconASrc} />
    ) : (
        <img src={iconBSrc} />
    )}

    {/* Or, even better */}
    <img src={(meetingType === something) ? iconASrc : iconBSrc} />
</div>
```

See [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for the latter two options.